# Branco no fundo do ecrã com ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

Coloquei um `ScrollView` num dos meus `layouts`, para permitir que utilizadores com ecrãs mais pequenos possam ver a informação toda.

O problema é que quando inicio a aplicação no meu telemóvel (5.5'') aparece-me uma faixa branca por cima do `layout`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código `xml` do `layout` é o seguinte:

```
 <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
    android:fillViewport="true"

    >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_apresentation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackGround">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagetoMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:contentDescription="ola"
        android:src="@drawable/cakelogomain"

        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txttoDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imagetoMain"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSecondBackGround"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texttoViewTodscr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txttoDescription"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/descriptionTwo"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSecondBackGround"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/idButton"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/texttoViewTodscr"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorSecondBackGround"
        android:text="@string/botaoMainTransition"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />



</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Alguém consegue me dar uma explicação do porquê disto acontecer?

Alguma forma melhor de adaptar os meus `layouts` a ecrãs mais pequenos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta colocar a altura do ScrollView pra ocupar o ecrã todo, exemplo:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
    android:fillViewport="true"
```

Altera para:

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: Obrigado Leonardo! Funcionou, um pequeno detalhe que me passou completamente ao lado! Esta é a melhor forma de apresentar em ecrãs pequenos, ou conhece outra? :)

Comment: Acredito ser a melhor forma, o *match_parent* vai fazer com que o ecrã se adapte a tela do usuário tanto na largura quanto na altura, e colocando a barra de rolagem somente quando necessário, se alguém abrir com um device de 6 polegadas, pode ser que a barra de rolagem nem apareça

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Leonardo! :)